# Angular repeating images

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

New to angular and developing a simple page just to learn the inner workings.  What I have is a div that display name price and description along with a button and a full image.  What I'm trying to do is underneath that full image display 2-3 additional images.  The problem is the same full image is displaying again and none of the additional images are displaying.

Here is the angular

```
(function () {

var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

app.controller('StoreController', function () {
    this.products = gems;
});

var gems = [
    {
        name: 'Defmei',
        price: 2.95,
        description: 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. ',
        canPurchase: true,
        soldOut: false,
        images: [
            {
                image: "Images/image1.jpg",
                image: "Images/image2.jpg",
                image: "Images/image3.jpg" 
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        name: 'Sijoi',
        price: 5.95,
        description: 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. ',
        canPurchase: true,
        soldOut: true,
        images: [

                {
                    image: "Images/image4.jpg",
                    image: "Images/image3.jpg",
                    image: "Images/image2.jpg"
                }
        ]
    }
]

})();
```

Here is the HTML

```
<body data-ng-controller="StoreController as store" >
<div class="display" data-ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>{{product.price | currency}}</h2>
    <p> {{product.description}} </p>

    <img class="imageStyles" data-ng-src="{{product.images[0].image}}"/> 
    <br />

    <div data-ng-repeat="image in product.images">
        <img data-ng-src="{{image.image}}" class="thumbs" />
    </div>
    <button data-ng-show="product.canPurchase">Add to cart</button>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images array only has one item in it with image defined three times. Change it like the following so that there are three separate items and it should work.

```
images: [
    {image: "Images/image4.jpg"},
    {image: "Images/image3.jpg"},
    {image: "Images/image2.jpg"}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

That image object seems "broken", you're practically redefining the image attribute 3 times.
In javascript, objects have a syntax like { attribName1: attValue1, attribName2: attValue2 ...}
What you're creating here:

```
images: [
        {
            image: "Images/image1.jpg",
            image: "Images/image2.jpg",
            image: "Images/image3.jpg" 
        }
    ]
```

Is an array with 1 item, which is an object, with 1 property, "image", with a value of... "Images/image3.jpg" maybe (or whatever, I wouldn't be surprised if double-defining attributes like this was in fact undefined behaviour).

What you probably want instead is either an array with 3 elements, or an object with 3 distinct attributes, ie:

```
images: [
        {
            "image1": "Images/image1.jpg",
            "image2": "Images/image2.jpg",
            "image3": "Images/image3.jpg" 
        }
    ]
```

You can iterate through array members and object attributes too with ng-repeat, but you have to change your code accordingly.